# Explain recursive function with static variable PHP

Tags: php, recursion, static-variables

Please help me to understand this exmaple? 
Why it prints "10" ten times? Why not 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9?

```
<?php
function test()
{
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;
    if ($count < 10) {
        test();
    }
    echo "\n$count";
}
test();
```

Comment: The best way to understand programs like this is to pretend you're the computer executing it. Write down the variable value on a piece of paper, and update it every time there's an assignment.

Comment: https://eval.in/private/6cca30523fbfc5

Comment: So function breaks itself somehow by two parts, before  "If" and after? Because of condition. And executes ten times first part at first and then ten times "echo"? I nearly understood it )) Thanks Anton, great example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's less than 10 it recurses and doesn't output, when it is 10, it falls to the `echo` and prints 10 for the 10 times that it recursed as it exits each time.

If you `echo` before recursing it will work as you describe.  Also, you need to output before you increment or you won't get `0`:

```
function test()
{
    static $count = 0;
    echo "\n$count";

    $count++;
    if ($count < 10) {
        test();
    }

}
test();
```